# Wrapped text should overlap an image above it

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on improving a webpage with a great amount of inherited, legacy code. One of the problems that occurs is to do with the wrapping of text lines in a fixed-height-and-width container, better explained by this image:

[image: Example images. First works, second is desired, third is reality.]

The first image is the normal behaviour and is what gets displayed if the text is short enough to fit into one line.

The second image displays the *desired* behaviour: If the text has to wrap, the container should expand in size and cover the lower part of the image appropriately. However, it does not overlap, so the third image is the resulting behaviour.

Dropping the fixed-width or fixed-height constraint is not feasible, it creates unpleasant irregularities. That was the case in the first place, so I'm trying to fix this.

I have tried working around it with `z-index` and `position`ing, but couldn't get it to work even in the slightest.

---

An example of a line that is wrapping due to length.

```css
.element {
  margin: 15px 7px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: #222;
  max-height: 523px;
  max-width: 300px;
}
.element img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.element h2 {
  text-align: center;
  background: #333333;
  padding: 12px 0;
  font: 400 16px/22px 'Roboto Slab',serif;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #333333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.element h2 a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 400 16px/22px 'Roboto Slab',serif;
}
.element span.view {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 12px 0;
  font: 400 16px/22px 'Roboto Slab',serif;
  margin: 0;
}
.element span.view a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333333;
}
body {
  background: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="element" sort-id="1">
  <a href="index.cfm?sendung_id=518">
    <img src="http://startv.ch/demandit/files/M_75AB1CC4DCE0B2C5F31/dms//Image/CC_Talk_Auslaenderkriminalitaet.jpg" 
         alt="CC_Talk_Auslaenderkriminalitaet.jpg" border="0"> 
  </a> 

  <span class="lower-part-of-element">
    <h2>
      <a href="index.cfm?sendung_id=518">Adrian Amstutz &amp; Esther Egger-Wyss</a>
    </h2>

    <span class="view">
      <a href="index.cfm?sendung_id=518">Ausländerkriminalität</a>
    </span> 
  </span>
</div>
```

Or on [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/Adowrath/pen/zEmgqL).

Comment: Do you have an example ? i would go with fixed height of the text div and oveflow hidden.

Comment: @MikeX There is both an inline snippet and an example on Codepen.io. Overflow hidden is not an option, we want to display the whole text of who's participating in the episode.

Comment: If you want to solve this keeping the legacy HTML intact, then your best bet is to absolutely position `.lower-part-of-element` from the bottom of the `.element` container. Add enough padding-bottom on the latter to "make room" for the _default_ amount of text you're expecting to fit under the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve this keeping the legacy HTML intact, then your best bet is to absolutely position `.lower-part-of-element` from the bottom of the `.element` container. Add enough padding-bottom on the latter to "make room" for the *default* amount of text you're expecting to fit under the image.

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px 7px;
  padding-bottom: 5.75em;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: #222;
  max-height: 523px;
  max-width: 300px;
}
.element .lower-part-of-element {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.element img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.element h2 {
  text-align: center;
  background: #333333;
  padding: 12px 0;
  font: 400 16px/22px 'Roboto Slab',serif;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #333333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.element h2 a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 400 16px/22px 'Roboto Slab',serif;
}
.element span.view {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 12px 0;
  font: 400 16px/22px 'Roboto Slab',serif;
  margin: 0;
}
.element span.view a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333333;
}
body {
  background: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="element" sort-id="1">
  <a href="index.cfm?sendung_id=518">
    <img src="http://startv.ch/demandit/files/M_75AB1CC4DCE0B2C5F31/dms//Image/CC_Talk_Auslaenderkriminalitaet.jpg" 
         alt="CC_Talk_Auslaenderkriminalitaet.jpg" border="0"> 
  </a> 

  <span class="lower-part-of-element">
    <h2>
      <a href="index.cfm?sendung_id=518">Adrian Amstutz &amp; Esther Egger-Wyss</a>
    </h2>

    <span class="view">
      <a href="index.cfm?sendung_id=518">blah blah blubb</a>
    </span> 
  </span>
</div>

<div class="element" sort-id="1">
  <a href="index.cfm?sendung_id=518">
    <img src="http://startv.ch/demandit/files/M_75AB1CC4DCE0B2C5F31/dms//Image/CC_Talk_Auslaenderkriminalitaet.jpg" 
         alt="CC_Talk_Auslaenderkriminalitaet.jpg" border="0"> 
  </a> 

  <span class="lower-part-of-element">
    <h2>
      <a href="index.cfm?sendung_id=518">Foo Bar</a>
    </h2>

    <span class="view">
      <a href="index.cfm?sendung_id=518">blah blah blubb</a>
    </span> 
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
.lower-part-of-element {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wrQwXY

Please also notice that you should change that `span` to a `div`.

Comment: Not quite, CBroe's answer was more accurate. Why do you suggest the change to a div though?

Comment: Because inline elements as span shouldn't contain block elements - more info here https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3. Anyway, glad you solved!

Comment: Ah, yeah. I somehow always forget this as it didn't cause me headaches (yet). Thanks :D